# Center text on top of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I need to center a text in an image. I've tried margin in the CSS code but is still isn't working. I'm using the images as a background to my text because it will simplify an animation that I will add later. If the image as a background doesn't work, I can always find a way around it. How can I do this? What I'm trying isn't working.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to include that the text I'm trying to center is the `.IOStext` (In CSS). I'm trying to get it in the middle of the `Moon`.

My Code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: UDFont;
  src: url(gomarice_gogono_cocoa_mochi.ttf);
}
body {
  background-image: url(background.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #101423;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'UDFont', Impact, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
#header {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
#headerContent {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
#mainTitle {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.universeTitle, .devTitle {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.universeTitle {
  color: #74aeee;
}
.devTitle {
  color: #f1ab3c;
}
.slogan {
  color: #822E81;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {

}
#selectors {

}
#IOSselector {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(IOSMoon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.IOStext {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome! | Universe Dev</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="headerContent">
        <div class="mainTitle">
          <span class="universeTitle">Universe </span><span class="devTitle">Dev</span>
        </div>
          <h3 class="slogan">Universal Development</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="selectors">
          <div id="IOSselector">
            <h1 class="IOStext">IOS</h1>
          </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<!-- END -->
```

Comment: `.universeTitle { display: block; }`

Comment: @jmw5598 Check edit.

Comment: the backround image won't display in the code snippet since it's local to your computer.  Do you just want it exactly in the center of the image (vertical and horizontal)?

Comment: Have you tried display table property for parent and then table-cell for text and vertical-align:middle?

Comment: Right! Sorry. I forgot about the local image. No, I was able to fix the problem. I wanted it vertically centered.

Comment: I wanted it to look as shown on the image (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BgXnqeXYfi3I6Vg-iNX_mCKpjUXcQUBh/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

You could use flex on your "moon" and then make you text inline-block:

```css
#IOSselector {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/300x300);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display:flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.IOStext {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="IOSselector">
  <h1 class="IOStext">IOS</h1>
</div>
```